# Horizontally Scroll one item at time in collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to scroll one collectionviewitem at time while scrolling horizontally. while in my case, when i try to swipe fast,multiple index scroll. when i scroll normal or slow it's work fine .but when try to scroll fast it creates issue.

I don't want to add NSTimer to make it delay. Please suggest any answer if anyone has regarding it except NSTimer.

The code which i used in scrollViewWillEndDragging

```
float pageWidth = (self.view.frame.size.width-20)/3 + 10; // width + space

        float currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        float targetOffset = targetContentOffset->x;
        float newTargetOffset = 0;

        if (targetOffset > currentOffset)
            newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;
        else
            newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;

        if (newTargetOffset < 0)
            newTargetOffset = 0;
        else if (newTargetOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width)
            newTargetOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width;

        targetContentOffset->x = currentOffset;

        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0) animated:YES];

        int index = newTargetOffset / pageWidth;

        return index;
```

[image]

Comment: What issue does it create? Do you want to disable completely the fast swipe? What method did you implement to create this effect? Did you override some scroll delegates method of it?

Comment: show your code how you are populating collectionView cell

Comment: [yourCollectionView setPagingEnabled:YES]; try this

Comment: Issue occurs when i try to scroll fast. Because i got newtargetoffset value max than what i get by normal swipe. Please help if anyone has an idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can disable the scroll, add a Swipe gesture instead.

Comment: No i can't do it now. My app is just about to finish and a lot of things will get mismatched. Need another alternate option.

Comment: did you add the pagination ?

Comment: No, i don't have any pagination here.